# Create classpath file using ant

Tags: java, ant, classpath

I was searching and searching for this but without any result.

I'm finally asking you the question: How can I create a classpath file for my java project using ant?
NB. I don't want the classpath to compile the sources, I just want to create the file.

The main idea is that I want to store on GIT only the skeleton of my java project, containing:

- src folder with java source files
- build.xml file

And with the help of ant, I want to create an eclipse project from this.

In the `build.xml` file I have a task that will create the `.project` file and another one that will copy some external jars from a remote location to my `/lib` folder.
After that, I want to create a `.classpath` file referencing those external libraries.

So far, I only succeeded to list all libraries line by line in the .classpath file:

```
<property name="line.separator" value="/n" />

<target name="createClasspath">
     <path id="class.path">
    <!-- include all jars in the lib directory and all sub-directories -->
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    </path>

    <pathconvert pathsep="${line.separator}" property="jars" refid="class.path">
        <!-- Add this if you want the path stripped -->
        <mapper>
            <flattenmapper />
        </mapper>
    </pathconvert>
    <echo file=".classpath">${jars}</echo>
</target>
```

**Output .classpath**

```
...
log4j-1.2.17.jar
jradius-client-2.0.0.jar
...
```

**Desired output .classpath**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jradius-client-2.0.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

How can I easily create the `.classpath` file with its classic structure?

Comment: How about having a template with you for desired .classpath and your ant file added the required value(s) in that template? Using for/sequential ant tasks?

Comment: Seems like you can add to your mapper to have the result be a classpathEntry element with your path  as the content of the current output and in combination with the https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoxml.html task referencing those resulting properties output what you want.

Comment: were you able to figure this out?  im trying to have ant  build a classpath file that vscode will automatically recognize